# Clean way to do sprite flashing?

Tags: c++, sprites

In old, 8-bit/16-bit games, sprites flashing every other frame were common. I don't want to use the hacks I've used before. Is there an elegant/clean way to do this? This is how I usually do it:

```
bool everyother = false;
// update
everyother = !everyother;
// draw
if (flashing && everyother)
    // do nothing
else
    // draw
```

Seems like a hack to me.

Comment: What do you mean by flashing?

Comment: Given the 8-bit/16-bit context, I believe Omega is referring to the effect where a sprite was only drawn every other frame (or every other N frames), causing it to "flicker," often in response to taking damage to indicate invincibility frames or something. This was also done in some cases to work around scanline sprite draw limits, as detailed in one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those unfamiliar with the concept, the proper term is **sprite flickering**. Old consoles like the NES could only display a certain number of sprites simultaneously, so to work around this limit and show more sprites, games would show them on alternating frames.

Your solution can get [quite complex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980198/2038264) if you want to properly emulate the effect, that is, ensure that only X number of sprites are shown simultaneously, which means coordinating the flickering between sprites.

But assuming you don't need to be that authentic and just fake the appearance, a boolean flag is pretty much the simplest way to do it, for 2-frame flickers.

Another method, which doesn't require extra state, is to check whether the current **game frame** is odd or even. E.g.

```
for (int game_frame = 0; ; game_frame++) {
    if (game_frame & 1) {
        sprite.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly inelegant or "unclean" about what you're doing already (toggling every frame), especially if you're also using a fixed framerate.

If you're *not* using a fixed framerate, you may want to consider a slight change to toggle the sprite visibility based on elapsed real-time instead, as this will ensure a more consistent flicker rate than tying it to a variable framerate would.

This looks basically the same:

```
void updateGame (float elapsedSeconds) {
  // ...

  flickerAccumulator += elapsedSeconds;
  if (flickerAccumulator >= 0.25f) {
    // Quarter-second flicker-on/flicker-off periods.
    sprite.visible = !sprite.visible;

    // You could just reset to 0 and probably be safe, this
    // attempts to account for "overflow" into the next
    // quarter-second period.
    flickerAccumulator -= 0.25f;
  }

  // ...
}
```